# Can someone identify this tree from the Pacific Northwest?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

A tree at my house in Seattle, Washington, USA has these leaves. Can someone tell me what it is?

[image: A tree at my house in Seattle]

Comment: Do you have a photo of the flowers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks similar to a *Cotinus coggygria*, which is a shrub that we call a Smokebush in the UK. But given your location, it could be *Cotinus obovatus*, known as American smoketree.

See http://dendro.cnre.vt.edu/dendrology/syllabus/factsheet.cfm?ID=415

The leaves will start green and progressively change colour to deep reds in the autumn with sprays of pink-purple flowers in the summer that from a distance look like smoke, hence the name.

Here are some images I have found on the web.

[image]
http://www.cirrusimage.com/tree_American_smoke.htm

[image]
http://allthedirtongardening.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/smoke-tree-smoke-bush-coninus.html

Comment: Hello Martin, could you explain why you think it is *Cotinus  sp*, ideally with links to references and images. You may also like to read [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and find many sample responses to some highly received species-id questions [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/species-identification?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a Chokecherry. [Prunus virginiana 'Canada Red'](http://www.urbanforestnursery.com/treeprofiles/profilecanadaredchokecherry.html)

Found this on a Washington nursery website so it would make sense that it would be planted in your region. I am inclined to think it is closer to this species than a smoke bush based off what I can see from the flower in the photograph.

Comment: Possibly, although the leaves appear to be smooth-edged, rather than serrated

Comment: That's a good point. I would have rather left a comment because not 100% sure, but didn't have enough reputation.